# Hadoop 2.6.0 Namenode stuck in safemode and won't leave it

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, redhat, safe-mode

I'm using Hadoop 2.6.0 on a multi-node cluster. Actually the cluster is virtual cluster and I have three machines on one PC. The host OS is Windows 7 64 bit with 3 GB Ram and the guests are Redhat Enterprise 6.4 32 bit that use VMware. One of these VMs is namenode and the others are datanode. Actually the datanode is master and the others are slaves. These VMs have 1 GB RAM. I created the cluster successfully and used it for a while. Since it got stuck when running jobs, i decided to format it and restart dfs and yarn.

Everything was good, but when i want to create a directory or put something in it, i face this message: `Namenode is in safe mode`.

I have tried to leave the safe mode using this command:
`hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`.

When I do it, it says `safe mode is OFF`, but when i try to make directory or put something in hdfs, it says "Namenode is in safemode"! I formatted and restarted cluster many times, but i get this error again and again. Here is some information:
[Status of nodes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/im3u8q1ap8ca39m/Screenshot1.png?dl=0)
[hosts files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/phw66tlup4li927/Screenshot2.png?dl=0)

Comment: Hi whats your replication factor which you specified for your cluster.?
Seems to be the problem is having the multiple node in same machine that share the common resource.

Comment: Please change the Replication factor to 1 and form the cluster. Even this to fails try to use the hadoop service in different machine! .

Comment: i did it, but it doesn't work, any idea? @karthik